# What Java libraries can I use to pull text and font styles?

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, nlp, apache-poi, apache-tika

I am working on a machine learning project (NLP), where I would like to use the text content and font styles to train the model to identify parts of a document. I found apache tika & POI, but I am struggling to figure out how to parse more than text.

Comment: For what file formats? Apache Tika will give you basic formatting if you ask it for XHTML, is that not enough?

Comment: My intent is to use the font styles and formatting to help direct the most optimal machine learning NLP model to parse information from the unstructured data. I am hoping that adding the formatting relationships would help optimize. The content is in resumes that come in all kinds of file formats and text formats.

The most popular formats are various word files & PDF's.

Comment: I just tried the toXMLcontentHandler class but almost everything came up as <p>

Comment: If people had styled their word document text, eg Heading 2, Tika would give you that in the xhtml. If they just make a bit bold and slightly larger, Tika ignores that to give "clean" xhtml. You'll need to go down a level to Apache POI to see the exact per-run formatting